# First Integral of the Hamiltonian System

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, control-theory, stability-theory

Consider the system
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \dot{q}_1=q_1 \cos(p_1-p_2) \\
& \dot{q}_2=-q_1 \cos(p_1-p_2) \\
& \dot{p}_1=-1 - \sin(p_1-p_2)\\
& \dot{p}_2=1\\
\end{aligned}
$$
I need to find a first integral that is independent of the Hamiltonian.
Incidentally, the Hamiltonian is $H=q_1 \sin(p_1-p_2) + q_1 - q_2$.

Thank you, in advance, for your response.

Comment: $q_1+q_2$ is an integral.

Comment: Thank you for your response, @Dmitry . That's right. I thought it should have non-zero coefficients for all variables in the phase space. Thank you.